gltf export file size is too large
i need a export of my blender project to gltf format to show real time on my website.
the output generating process working good but the size of file is about 155 mb and the output have a lot of detail and also is editable (i can click on object and move them.)
im using this command for export
 bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=filepath, export_jpeg_quality=75 )

is there a way to get light export to show online in browser? just with zoom and 360^ view?

Surely that's down to whatever application you are using to view it on your web site, nothing to do with Blender!

you mean there is no option in blender to minimize the size or ignore details? 155 mb is to large at all!!

What John means is that the ability  to edit a model is a characteristic of the application you open it with, not of the model itself. Export size is mostly dependent on the complexity of the model, if the size is too big, simplify it.

just adding export_materials ='NONE',export_unused_images=False,export_colors=True to bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf reduced the size to 12mb from 155mb and reduced export time to 2second from 22 second.. im speaking about options guys..


Is there a way to get light export to show online in browser? just with zoom and 360^ view?

When the option for punctual lighting is enabled in the glTF export settings (it is disabled by default), glTF exports may include directional, point, and spot lights. To use them viewers must support the KHR_lights_punctual glTF extension, which is widely supported.
However, creating matching lighting conditions in another 3D renderer remains very difficult. Getting the units of the lighting correct is not enough, the camera exposure and tone mapping also come into play substantially, and cannot be included in exports. Blender's exporter has some options for the lighting units, but practically speaking — it's usually best and simplest to choose a simple HDR for lighting and try to use that in both Blender and the viewer. HDRs are not included in exports, and would be provided to your viewer of choice separately.

the size of file is about 155 mb and the output have a lot of detail

It's difficult to comment on file size without knowing what that 155mb is comprised of. Loading the model in a tool like https://gltf.report/ should give you a better idea, look for the total sizes of meshes, textures, and animation keyframes.
There are a lot of optimization tools for glTF. Two free and open source options include gltfpack and glTF Transform, both are CLI tools. Once installed (separately), gltfpack can be enabled in the preferences panel for the Blender glTF addon (requires Blender 4.1), adding a new section to the exporter options, and reducing the size of mesh geometry and animation keyframes. Blender also supports Draco compression in the exporter settings, which compresses mesh geometry — this option is mutually exclusive with gltfpack.
If the size of your model is mostly textures, there's little in Blender to address that other than reducing resolution, and you will likely need an external tool like glTF Transform that can compress textures to WebP, AVIF, or KTX2 texture formats.
